# Which version of AIDL should I download?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, aidl, buildozer

I am trying to use buildozer to make App from my python-kivy file. When I run "buildozer android debug deploy run" to make an app, it comes with this error:

```
Aidl not found, please install it.
```

So, I tried to download Aidl by this command:

```
~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;29.0.0"
```

but that does not work. So maybe I am not downloading the proper version. Which version of Aidl should I download?

More info:  Ubuntu version: 16.04. I know I have to mention the version of ndk and sdk, but I do not know how to find their versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buildozer can download NDK and SDK by itself, but better you do it yourself. Unzip it and then write paths to NDK and SDK folders in the .spec file.